# Order of group $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, finite-groups, prime-numbers

Given $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$, a general linear group, where $p$ is a prime number, how does one determine the order of this group?

We have $n^2$ elements in a matrix $A \in GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$, and each element may have $p$ possibilities for numbers. But one condition has to be satisfied - that $\det A \in \mathbb{Z}^*_p$. So there will be $p$ determinants in total. That's where I get stuck.

Comment: To construct an element of $GL_n(\Bbb F_p)$, pick the first column, then the second, and so on.

Comment: @BenLim Surely you are aware that lots of people write $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for the cyclic ring of $p$ elements, which is also the field of $p$ elements. So in this context, $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $\mathbb{F}_p$ are the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Follow @anon's hint. How many *vectors* are there that you could use to fill the first column? The only vector you could not use is the zero vector.

Then how many *vectors* are there that you could use to fill the second column? Remember that the second vector would need to be linearly independent from the first.

And the third column? And so on.

Comment: Is it correct that for the first vector we have $pn$ choices, for the second we have $pn-1$, and for the $n$-th vector we have $pn-n$ choices. Therefore, a total of $pn(pn-1)(pn-2)...(pn-n)$ choices are possible for a matrix in this group?

Comment: @sequence Close. There are $p^n$ vectors in $\mathbb{Z}_p^n$, but you have to exclude the zero vector. So the first column could be $p^n-1$ things. How many vectors do you have to then exclude as options for the second column? And then for the third, and so on? Without giving it all away, the final result is $\left(p^n-1\right)\left(p^n-\mathord{?}\right)\left(p^n-\mathord{?}\right)\cdots\left(p^n-\mathord{?}\right)$.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. For the first vector there should be $p^n-1$, for the second one $p^n-2$, and for the $n$-th one $p^n-n$. Then the total would be $(p^n-1) ... (p^n-n)$ matrices in this group. Would this be a correct approach? (Actually I wrote this before I saw your upper comment :).

Comment: No. For the second column, it's not enough to exclude only the zero vector and whichever vector you used in the first column. Any _multiple_ of that vector is also off limits for the second column. It's best if you start viewing the collection of things to exclude as a vector space. It'll make the counting easier.

Comment: But what multiples can there be if we're dealing with $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

Comment: Any nonzero vector $\vec{v}$ has $p-1$ nonzero multiples: $\vec{v},2\vec{v},3\vec{v},\ldots$.

Comment: Yes, but when we say $(p^n−1)...(p^n−n)$, we are already not counting any multiples.

Comment: Here's the answer: $\left(p^n-p^0\right)\left(p^n-p^1\right)\left(p^n-p^2\right)\cdots\left(p^n-p^{n-1}\right)$

Comment: Yes, I now understand the thing about multiples of vectors (initially I for some reason somehow thought in terms of $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ instead of in terms of $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Can you please clarify how exactly you excluded the multiples?